# How to sort dictionaries and create a dictionaries based on the values in the list inside the dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

This is a challenging one for me tried for hours as I am learning but I am not sure if my logic is correct at all.

Define a function called stars that takes in two dictionaries:

movies: a dictionary where the keys are movie titles and
the values are lists of major performers in the movie.
For example:

```
movies["The Dark Knight"] = ["Christian Bale",
"Heath Ledger", "Maggie Gyllenhall", "Aaron Eckhart"]
```

tv shows: a dictionary where the keys are TV show titles
and the values lists of major performers in the show.
For example:

```
tvshows["Community"] = ["Joel McHale", "Alison
Brie", "Danny Pudi", "Donald Glover", "Yvette Brown"]
```

The function stars should return a new dictionary. The keys of the new dictionary should be the performers' names, and the values for each key should be the list of shows and
movies in which that performer has appeared. Sort the shows
and movies alphabetically.

If your function works correctly, this will originally print (although the order of the keys may vary):

```
{'Portia de Rossi': ['Arrested Development'], 'Will Ferrell': ['The Lego Movie'], 'Yvette Brown': ['Community'], 'Rebel Wilson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Danny Pudi': ['Community'], 'Elizabeth Banks': ['30 Rock', 'The Lego Movie'], 'Alec Baldwin': ['30 Rock'], 'Alison Brie': ['Community', 'How to Be Single', 'The Lego Movie'], 'Tina Fey': ['30 Rock'], 'Dakota Johnson': ['How to Be Single'], 'Joel McHale': ['Community'], 'Jack McBrayer': ['30 Rock'], 'Tracy Morgan': ['30 Rock'], 'Donald Glover': ['Community'], 'Will Arnett': ['Arrested Development', 'The Lego Movie'], 'Jason Bateman': ['Arrested Development']}

movies = {"How to Be Single": ["Alison Brie", "Dakota Johnson",
                               "Rebel Wilson"],
          "The Lego Movie": ["Will Arnett", "Elizabeth Banks",
                             "Alison Brie", "Will Ferrell"]}

tvshows = {"Community": ["Alison Brie", "Joel McHale",
                         "Danny Pudi", "Yvette Brown",
                         "Donald Glover"],
           "30 Rock": ["Tina Fey", "Tracy Morgan", "Jack McBrayer",
                       "Alec Baldwin", "Elizabeth Banks"],
           "Arrested Development": ["Jason Bateman", "Will Arnett",
                                    "Portia de Rossi"]}



print(stars(movies, tvshows))


def stars(movies, tv_shows):
    # print(movies)
    # print(tv_shows)
    dictionary_to_return = {}
    both_dict = {**movies, **tv_shows}
    # print(both_dict)
    celebrity_list = []
    # # print(celebrity_list)
    for (key, value) in both_dict.items():
        celebrity_list.extend(value)
        celebrity_list_filtered = list(set(celebrity_list))
    celebrity_list_filtered.sort()
    # print(celebrity_list_filtered)
    for every_celebrity in celebrity_list_filtered:
        # print(every_celebrity,": THis is artist")
        for every_title in both_dict.keys():
            # print(every_title,": THis is the tile")
            artist_in_title = both_dict[every_title]
            # print(artist_in_title, ":these are artist in the", every_title)
            if every_celebrity in artist_in_title:
                if every_title not in dictionary_to_return.keys():
                    celebrity_list.append(every_title)

                else:
                    valuess = dictionary_to_return[every_celebrity].value
                    print(valuess)
                print(celebrity_list)
    print(dictionary_to_return)
                # print(type(artist_in_title))
                # (every_celebrity,)
    # ret_list =[]
    # individual_tilte_list=[]
    # ret_dict ={}
    # for every_celebrity in celebrity_list_filtered:
    #     # print(every_celebrity)
    #     for (each_title,value) in both_dict.items():
    #         if every_celebrity in both_dict[each_title]:
    #             ret_list.append(every_celebrity)
    #             ret_list.append(key)
    # print(ret_list)
    # for i in range(0, len(ret_list)):
    #     if ret_list[i] in celebrity_list_filtered:
    #         if ret_list[i] in individual_tilte_list:
    #             individual_tilte_list.append(ret_list[0+i])
    #     elif ret_list[i] not in celebrity_list_filtered:
    #         individual_tilte_list.append(ret_list[i])
    # print(individual_tilte_list)
```

Above is the code I worked on which I feel is total trash. Some feedback on how to approach this problem will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need.

```
def stars(movies, tv_shows):
    dictionary_to_return = {}
    for k, v in {**movies, **tv_shows}.items():
        for actor in v:
            dictionary_to_return.setdefault(actor, []).append(k)

    # dictionary_to_return = {k: sorted(v) for k,v in dictionary_to_return.items()}  #Sort by show-movie
    return dictionary_to_return

print(stars(movies, tvshows))
```

**Output:**

```
{'Alec Baldwin': ['30 Rock'],
 'Alison Brie': ['How to Be Single', 'The Lego Movie', 'Community'],
 'Dakota Johnson': ['How to Be Single'],
 'Danny Pudi': ['Community'],
 'Donald Glover': ['Community'],
 'Elizabeth Banks': ['The Lego Movie', '30 Rock'], 
 'Jack McBrayer': ['30 Rock'],
 'Jason Bateman': ['Arrested Development'],        
 'Joel McHale': ['Community'],
 'Portia de Rossi': ['Arrested Development'],      
 'Rebel Wilson': ['How to Be Single'],
 'Tina Fey': ['30 Rock'],
 'Tracy Morgan': ['30 Rock'],
 'Will Arnett': ['The Lego Movie', 'Arrested Development'],
 'Will Ferrell': ['The Lego Movie'],
 'Yvette Brown': ['Community']}
```